# Cmake - Documentation

Tags: cmake

I use clang, gcc (and also their arm version).

is there somewhere a documentation, where i can see which values the following 2 arguments take:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME <value>)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR <value>)
```

i cannot find any doc, where cmake lists every possible input.
i just see that you have to assign a value to those, but what options do i have?

like system name: Linux is one, how about Windows?
And then what about processors, arm, x86, x86_64 (amd64)...

would be cool if someone knows a good source of documentation.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [CMake wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/CrossCompiling) about cross compiling:

> Once the system and the compiler are determined by CMake, it loads the
> corresponding files in the following order:
>
> - `Platform/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}.cmake` (optional, but issues a stern
>   warning)
> - `Platform/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-<compiler>.cmake`
>   (optional)
> - `Platform/${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}-<compiler>-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}.cmake`
>   (optional)

So, for find out all possible values for variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` you could check filenames under [Modules/Platform](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules/Platform) and extract the first part of every filename.

As for `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` variable, its only purpose is to include the latter file (of 3 components in the filename). From the same wiki:

> This variable is not used very much except for one purpose,
> it is used to load a `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME-compiler-CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR.cmake` file,
> which can be used to modify settings like compiler flags etc. for the target.
> You probably only have to set this one if you are using a cross compiler
> where every target hardware needs special build settings.

Comment: ok but if i am not cross compiling? example: i use cmake for cross compilation to ARM, but i run also unittests on linux and windows, and with gcc and/or clang.

i have for each option a toolchain setup, but i dont know how to setup the values as there is no documentation for this.

Comment: "but if i am not cross compiling?" - Eh? Setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` **implies** that you are cross-compiling. As for **description** for values of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, I am unsure about existence of a **single document** which **describes all** possible values. However, there could be documents describing **particular** values. Note, that Stack Overflow is a wrong place for a *request-for-documentation-references*. You could, however, **try** to use a particular value for `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` and ask about a **specific problem** you have faced in that usage.